# how to pass a variable to queryselectorAll?

Tags: javascript

Hi I want to pass a variable to queryselectorAll. I tried a couple of things but non have worked for me. I'm doing that because in my code I change the variable to a new one every time a click a button.

```
 var container = document.getElementById(containerBox.id)
 // I want containerBox.id to be called in querySelectorAll
 templateDiv = document.querySelectorAll('#' + 'containerBox.id' + 'template')[0].content.firstElementChild
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: + containerBox.id +

Comment: What kind of value is `containerBox`?

Comment: @FelixKling a div

Comment: @juvian I tried that already it didn't go work

Comment: If you already have a reference to the element, why are you calling `document.getElementById(containerBox.id)` again? It will return the same element, i.e. `containerBox === document.getElementById(containerBox.id)`.

Comment: Please provide a complete example. We don't know what the values are that you are working with and we don't know which element(s) you are trying to fetch. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: You need to explain what you trying to solve. It might not be in the `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Well the problem was not querySelectorAll it was something else and now it is solved @CallMeLaNN . It was just an empty variable :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question can be simplified to: How do I construct a string from fixed parts and a variable part?

The answer to that is:

```
'#' + containerBox.id + 'template'
```

(i.e. just don't put quotes around your variable name).

But why bother using `.querySelectorAll()` just to grab the first index? You could simply call `.querySelector()` instead.

And if all you need to get is an element with a specified id, you can just do this:

```
document.getElementById(containerBox.id + 'template')
```

... which is the method you're already using in your first line.